numpy.histogram is there a way to get a binning so there is at least one count per bin?
I'm using numpy.histogram on my data and then I want to perform a fit to some curve where the number of occurrences in each bin is dividing, so it cannot be zero. So I need the bins to contain at least one count. Is there anyway to do that with numpy.histogram or numpy.histogram_bin_edges?
This is just an example:
import numpy as np

sizes = np.array([
    1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4,
    9, 9, 7, 9, 10, 10, 20, 21,
])
hist, bins = np.histogram(sizes)
print(hist)
print(bins)

Returns:
[5 3 0 1 5 0 0 0 0 2]
[ 1.  3.  5.  7.  9. 11. 13. 15. 17. 19. 21.]

The idea is to avoid testing different number of bins manually.
The fitting function is f(N) = A/N**S, where N is an integer number. Regular binning is not mandatory. In the code example sizes are just some integer random numbers I chose.

Can you provide a meaningful example?

I have just added an example.

Please, specify: do you want a regular binning (like in your example: 3-1=5-3=7-5=...=2)? If yes, it seems hard: it is possible to build counter examples where all binning (but nbin=2) would fail. An "almost regular" one (in which case, it looks more like a quantile thing). Or just any one? (in which case, any greedy algorithm would do)

You provided an example of what you don't want, rather give us examples of what you would expect in such cases. You must make the expected logic fully clear.

Must bins have the same size ? Can a small number such 1e-7 be added to the bin counts ? Could you tell us more about the function that cannot have zero count ?

@chrslg and jlandercy I added the information requested.

@mozway I don't expect anything in particular, I guess there are many possible binnings that can satisfy my request, if bins are irregular.

That's the issue, SO is about building Q/A for specific problems, here it seems too vague to be answerable

But it's strange to me that numpy.histogram_bin_edges doesn't seems to have that functionality. Maybe I was missing something, so I asked. I still think the problem is specific enough: binning so that at least there is one count per bin; but you are right, there might be multiple algorithms for that specific for each conditions.

Depending on how much data points you have, you can change to an unbinned likelihood fit. This would avoid the binning issue overall.
